# Which component of a computer executes a game's source code?(cpu or gpu)

Tags: gpu, cpu

I wanted to know if i create a small pc game with graphics,Which component(cpu or gpu) is responsible for handling the execution of the code section and which component is responsible for handling graphics?

Is code section is run by both CPU or GPU?

Thank you for helping!!

Comment: The question likely requires a quite broad answer, because in its simplest form, the CPU executes your game code and the GPU draws the primitives you give it. However, in todays games, you feed the GPU not just geometry and textures, you also feed it code. So in reality, both the CPU and the GPU executes code. However, it depends entirely on how you structure your drawing code.

Comment: The CPU (**Central** processing unit) handles the general program flow and the GPU (**Graphics** processing unit) is/can be used to offload the graphics code.